# PHP, symfony list data in table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

This is a project for school!!!
Let's say that I want to store and show working hours in an HTML table.

I want something like, 'if' the date from DB which user added is equal to the date from the weekly calendar than show me an EDIT button else show me an ADD button?

I want to show Add for the rest of the users who didn't create any data in DB.

```
<table class="table" id="week">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">users</th>
        {% for day in days %}
            <th class="{{ day|date("D-d") }}">
                <span>{{ day|date("D") }}</span>
                <span>{{ day|date("d") }}</span>
            </th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr class="days">
        <th scope="row">{{ users.username }}</th>
        {% for day in days %}
        <td id="my_cell {{ day|date("d-m") }}">
            {% for time in findTime %}
                {% if d|date("d-m-Y") == time.date|date('d-m-Y') and users.id == time.getUser().id %}
                     {{ time.timeFrom|date("H:i") }} - {{ time.timeTo|date("H:i") }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>    
        {% endfor %}  
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am currently using DB doctrine ORM on symfony 3.4v

I don't have an idea how to solve this problem, I tried with different array function in PHP but I did not find solutions.

Thank you for understanding.

Comment: if d|date("d-m-Y")    is the variable  "d" right. maybe you need to write "day"?

Comment: Yes “day” syntax mistake :)

Comment: is it resolved the issue?

Comment: @create'it not yet

Comment: 1. Please paste findTime, 
2. Maybe `time.getUser().id` is wrong, write `time.user.id` instead

Comment: @create'it I found another solutions with css:hover, so for the moment It’s enough. Thank you